# Re-compiler QtEmbedded in OpenEmbedded without Examples

Tags: qtembedded

I have a touch panel computer running ARM9. I have successfully built a QtEmbedded SDK image under OpenEmbedded toolchain (I am newbie in this area) for ARM9. I'd like to re-build QtEmbedded images again with few examples that it comes (not all)  with due to space limitation on NAND. How can I re-compile this. I have commented out examples in examples.pro but it seems it's building images from existing packages. I am using command:  bitbake -b qt4-embedded-image

Please help.

- Nimesh

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-run the configure step of the bitbake to rebuild the Makefiles from the .pro files.  You can do this by removing the configure stamp for this package.  Just rm the do_configure stamp for this package and re-run the bitbake command you did above.